# Can remote (http communication protocol) XP clients consume services hosted in IIS 7?

Tags: wcf

I'm quite new to WCF currently studying Learning WCF. Maybe I missed something while reading about hosting, but it's not very clear to me if XP clients can consume services hosted on IIS 7 (windows 7 machine).

Does the operating system of the client play any role when it comes to consuming services hosted in different enviroments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes they can consume them, no the OS *should **not*** matter.

The reasons being that the services are served using platform independent mechanisms, such as returning data in [SOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP)/XML/other standardised formats.